# SP Ent 2013: Search Broken after URL change and SSL addition

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search

We have changed how our new Sharepoint 2013 environment is accessed. 
Initially it was accessed via the internal network server name (ie: srv-sharepoint) over http to it's external name sp.ourserver.org over https

Everything seems to be working fine except that the search is now broken and returns 'Sorry, something went wrong'. This happens on both the global search centre (enterprise) and subsite searches.

We have deleted the Search Service Application and created it via Powershell using the following script.

```
$saAppPoolName = "Default SharePoint Service App Pool"
$searchServerName = (Get-ChildItem env:computername).value
$serviceAppName = "Search Service Application"
$searchDBName = "SearchService_DB"
$saAppPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool $saAppPoolName
Write-Host "Starting Search Service Instances..."
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance $searchServerName
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $searchServerName
Write-Host "Creating Search Service Application and Proxy..."
$searchServiceApp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name $serviceAppName -ApplicationPool $saAppPoolName -DatabaseName $searchDBName
$searchProxy = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -Name "$serviceAppName Proxy" -SearchApplication $searchServiceApp
Write-Host "Configuring Search Component Topology..."
$clone = $searchServiceApp.ActiveTopology.Clone()
$searchServiceInstance = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance
New-SPEnterpriseSearchAdminComponent –SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance
New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentProcessingComponent –SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance
New-SPEnterpriseSearchAnalyticsProcessingComponent –SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance 
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent –SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance 
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent –SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent –SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance
$clone.Activate()
```

**Central Admin -> App Mgmt -> Manage Web Apps**
Sharepoint on port 443

**Central Admin -> Service Apps -> Manage Service Apps**
Search Service Application

- Content Sources
  Start URL: https ://sp.ourserver.org
  Crawl Rule: https ://sp.ourserver.org/* (include all items in this path)
  Crawl Log: Has Successes
  Server Name Mappings: http ://srv-sharepoint -> https ://sp.ourserver.org

I am at a complete loss as to what to try next. Any thoughts?

on further investigation, in the event log

```
An exception occurred while updating addresses for connected app {8baf914c-e2f0-4345-9b79-3917893fdffa_1f943e58-fddd-4f7e-bf67-39d098271edd}. The uri endpoint information may be stale. System.InvalidOperationException: The requested application could not be found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.ProcessCommonExceptions(Uri endpointAddress, String operationName, Exception ex, SPServiceLoadBalancerContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.GetEndPoints(Guid serviceId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPConnectedServiceApplicationAddressesRefreshJob.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
```

After running an SQL query on the config database i get

```
<object type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPConnectedServiceApplication, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"><sFld type="Guid" name="m_ApplicationId">8baf914c-e2f0-4345-9b79-3917893fdffa</sFld><fld type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Uri, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="m_ApplicationAddresses"><sFld type="Uri">http://SRV-SHAREPOINT:32843/8baf914ce2f043459b793917893fdffa/SearchService.svc</sFld></fld><fld type="System.Collections.Hashtable, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="m_UpgradedPersistedFields" /><fld name="m_Properties" type="null" /><sFld type="String" name="m_LastUpdatedUser">BBH\SP_Farm</sFld><sFld type="String" name="m_LastUpdatedProcess">OWSTIMER (5052)</sFld><sFld type="String" name="m_LastUpdatedMachine">SRV-SP2013</sFld><sFld type="DateTime" name="m_LastUpdatedTime">2015-05-05T16:45:00</sFld></object>
```

Comment: When do you get the error message that something went wrong? When trying to access the search service or when performing a search?

Comment: Can you share the AAM configuration for your web applications?

Comment: @user19952 When i perform a search

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott  
  
https://srv-sharepoint  Default https://srv-sharepoint   
https://sp.ourserver.org  Extranet https://sp.ourserver.org   
http://srv-sharepoint:16645  Default http://srv-sharepoint:16645

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott  This has since been updated to https: //sp.ourserver.org default https: //sp.ourserver.org. Half of the search is now working (the left of the search content, by author, modified date) but the content is still showing an error.

Comment: I removed the orphan config entry and recreated the search proxy, reindexed and it started working.